# How can I link to Emacs *Help* from Org mode?

Tags: org-mode, help-mode

I am writing documentation for some emacs-lisp code.

The code has docstrings, but I am writing a manual using org-mode.

It would be cool if I could embed links to the code within this manual. Click on the link, and it brings up the Enacs Help function (describe variable or function) on it.

So I guess really what I am asking for is a way to link to the two Emacs help functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to create an org-mode link that opens help?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61730/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-org-mode-link-that-opens-help)

Answer (score 7):

You can include arbitrary `elisp` code as a link, so something like this works:

```
[[elisp:(describe-function 'find-file)][find-file]]
```

This displays as **find-file**, and when you click it, it opens the help for `find-file`.

By default, Emacs will ask you to confirm that you want to run the elisp code, as this could potentially be dangerous. You can turn off this check by customizing the variable `org-link-elisp-skip-confirm-regexp`. For example, setting it to ".*" will cause all lisp to be evaluated without confirmation.

Comment: There is a better method: using `help` links. See the duplicate question for details.